# Converting string with int and dictionary to list

Tags: python, string

I have a string `str = '[1,"a",3,{1:2 , 4:5}]'` and I have to convert `str` to list such that `L = [1,"a",3,{1:2 , 4:5}]` in python.

Comment: Hi! Please provide some context of your problem, show your research effort and code attempt
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Please add your attempt with your post,
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in `eval()` function as so:

```py
str = '[1,"a",3,{1:2 , 4:5}]'
new = eval(str)

print(new)  # returns [1, 'a', 3, {1: 2, 4: 5}]
```